# how tuple process in storm topology?

Tags: apache, apache-storm

**description about topology:**

[image]

spout continuously sends tuple to read bolt.

read bolt processes and send the result to next bolt and so on.

**situation:**

1 spout sends tuple 1 to read bolt

2 read bolt gives tuple 1 to write bolt

3 write bolt gives tuple 1 to R bolt

4 R bolt processes tuple 1

**when tuple 2 sends from spout?**

after processing tuple 1 in R bolt or after readbolt sends tuple1 to write bolt?

Answer (score 0):

Spout and Bolt tasks are all run in parallel, not one by one, see [Understanding the Parallelism of a Storm Topology](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html) for more details